# Openssl vs. Opentnl

Tags: c++, openssl

While searching the web looking for a networking library I came across the two and I began reading what the were about. Correct me if I am wrong but my understanding is that Opentnl is for sending stuff between a client and a server while Openssl is for securing that connection. In the case that this conclusion is correct, would it be possible to use the two in Union? ( With some work implementing of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is possible. You can use the encryption API in OpenSSL and build your own encrypted data to communicate via the Torque Net lib. It isn't something you can just plug in, and isn't as simple as the TCP socket stuff in OpenSSL, but I've done something similar to write a UDP based VPN with SSLeay (predecessor to OpenSSL). As an example, you can initialize a "session" of your own using RSA, then encrypt/decrypt from a buffer with AES (or some other algorithm that has hardware support for least latency).

I don't actually know much about TNL, it may already include some encryption support. I'd check that first.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for. I am new to network programing so I will have to research that termenology but I am sure it will help me in the long run though the term VPN isn't new to me.